# How to grayscale video stream using keyboard?

Tags: python, opencv

I need a python script that live stream cam and I wanna grayscale the stream using keyboard, but I can't, every time I run the blow code stream change to grayscale but after a second it return to normal, please help me to fix this

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    elif c & 0xFF == ord('3'):
        frame=gray
    cv2.imshow('a',frame)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I need to change it using keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the keyboard capture. The code waits for a keyboard input every iteration of the loop, if it gets none then `none` is passed to the code i.e. it doesnt remember what you typed last time so your `elif` is not entered the next time around.

Try the following to see what is happening...

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

gray_flag = False
while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    c = cv2.waitKey(1) # only waits for 1 millisecond!!!
    if c & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    elif c & 0xFF == ord('3'):
        gray_flag = True
    elif c & 0xFF == ord('4'):
        gray_flag = False

    if gray_flag:
        cv2.imshow('a', gray)
    else:
        cv2.imshow('a', frame)


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The `gray_flag` ensures that your choice is remembered

Comment: Why not only convert if the gray flag is True?

Comment: @MohitMotwani  no reason except I thought the more verbose code was easier to understand given the code in the OP